# why does == creates compilation error on different types in Kotlin

Tags: compiler-errors, kotlin

The following code cannot be compiled:

```
if ("2" == 3) {
  //do something
}
```

`Error: Kotlin: Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'String' and 'Int'`

However, Kotlin docs say this is structural equality and is translated to `a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null)`: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html .

So what is really going on here? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

this is a Kotlin bug reported as [KT-4071](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4071) in youtrack, and the priority is `Major`, so I think it will be fixed quickly. for example:

```
val ok = "2".equals(3) // works fine
val error = "2" == 3 // compilation error
```

Comment: I think the bug is talking about a related warning and not the error itself which looks deliberate.

Comment: @oshai No. the reporter described it exactly a compilation error reported as: **"EQUALITY_NOT_APPLICABLE"**. and the reporter want such an error turn into a warning instead.

Comment: probably you are right. but, the bug was created on 12 Oct 2013 so I suspect JB do not intend to change how it behaves.

Comment: @oshai maybe, or maybe the priority was changed recently and consider to fix it in later version.

Comment: I think this is intended. Their types are different, and you know that they must be not equal in the compilation time (both already not null). If you know that they are different before running, why do you even compare them? It is always false. It only increases the chance of missing appending a method (like `.toString()`) or so.

Comment: At this time we have no plans to change the behavior of == with regard to types.